# How to Prove that if ϕ ⊨ ψ then ∀x.ϕ ⊨ ∀x.ψ. in formal language

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I wonder about the format of proof. I already knew the basic first order language syntax. But I still can't get a hint of how propositions can be proved.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Uou can use $\forall x \phi(x) \vDash \phi(x)$ and Generalization.

Comment: Relevant: [Universal instantiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_instantiation) and [Universal generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_generalization)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA thanks, and could you explain how can I use universal generalization here? I know that it means  ∀xP(x) is true, given the premise that P(c) is true for all elements c in the domain.

Comment: This is the proof I write down just now. Is it correct?      Given J. Assume that ⟦∀x.ϕ⟧J=T. Given a in J’s domain, ⟦ ψ⟧(J[x↦a])=T because ⟦ ϕ⟧_(J[x↦a])=T ϕ ⊨ ψ So ⟦∀x.ψ⟧_J=T. QED.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you, I have already solved this problem.